# How to tell when a spawned process is idle

Tags: node.js, process, spawn

I am launching an external program ([adb shell](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#shellcommands)) via node's `spawn` method.
Then I am sending commands via `childProc.stdin.write(input)` and the shell returns stuff accordingly.
My data callback gets called each time there is a new data chunk available. All good!

But since the connection stays open, I don't know when the external program is finished sending data.
Is there a way to solve this? Isn't there some standard way of showing "that's the data you asked for, I am done returning"?

```
  static async execCommand2(command, args, input) {

    if(!this.adbShellProc || this.adbShellProc.killed){
      this.adbShellProc = spawn(command, args)
      this.adbShellProc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
    }

    const self = this

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
      log.debug('Shell.execCommand2:', command, 'args:', args)
      log.debug('send input: ', input)
      
      self.adbShellProc.stdin.write(input)
      self.adbShellProc.stdin.write('\n')
      
      self.adbShellProc.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
        // resolve(chunk)
        // PROBLEM: I can't resolve here, cause there might be more data coming in 
      })
      self.adbShellProc.on('close', code => {
        self.adbShellProc.stdin.end()
        self.adbShellProc = null
      })   
    })
    return promise
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure your answer is in your question itself. You have added close event listener, so when process is ended, your control will be in close event(Just one modification is, close event will be of adbShellProc.stdout), so you can resolve/return data from there.

```
  static async execCommand2(command, args, input) {
   let finalOutcome = ''
    if(!this.adbShellProc || this.adbShellProc.killed){
      this.adbShellProc = spawn(command, args)
      this.adbShellProc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
    }

    const self = this

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
      log.debug('Shell.execCommand2:', command, 'args:', args)
      log.debug('send input: ', input)
      
      self.adbShellProc.stdin.write(input)
      self.adbShellProc.stdin.write('\n')
      
      self.adbShellProc.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
        // resolve(chunk)
        finalOutcome += data
        // PROBLEM: I can't resolve here, cause there might be more data coming in 
      })
      self.adbShellProc.stdout.on('close', code => {
        self.adbShellProc.stdin.end()
        self.adbShellProc = null
        resolve(finalOutcome)
      })   
    })
    return promise
  }
```

Also, it has another event end of stdout,

```
ls.stdout.on('end', (d) =>{
// You can resolve from here also
})
```

You can get more details here [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: "But since the **connection stays open**" - not sure how this answer deals with this point of the question. Can you elaborate, please

Comment: @x00 adb shell just does not quit by itself. It just prints data and then waits for more input. So my question was: How can I know that adb shell is waiting for more input. Or phrased differently. How can I know that adb shell is done processing my command I just sent.

Comment: @stoefln, that's not my answer :). And I have the same doubts about this solution

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no way of knowing if the output is final unless an exit code is returned, this is the linux way.

Fortunately, adb shell gives you a way of running one off commands using the adb shell without having to start it in interactive mode.

Instead of starting the shell and then sending the commands as input, make the whole thing a single command. Example:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

Then the close event will give you a clear indication that the command has finished so you can resolve and you will also get the return code, so you can check if the command has succeeded or not.

There's no real benefit in starting adb shell in interactive mode, because the real processing is not happening in adb but in the actual server, which is adbd.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#shellcommands

```
static async execCommand2(command, args, input) {
    let finalOutcome = ''
    //append the input to the arguments and don't use this, all your commands are one offs and do not require a state check
    let adbShellProc = spawn(command, args+input)
    adbShellProc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    log.debug('Shell.execCommand2:', command, 'args:', args+input)
    self.adbShellProc.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
        finalOutcome += data
    })
    self.adbShellProc.stdout.on('close', code => {
        //unix return code, 0 is good, not zero means error
        if(code != 0){
            reject(finalOutcome)
        }
        resolve(finalOutcome)
    })   
    })
    return promise
}
```

Comment: Spawning a new process comes with a certain overhead. That's why don't favour your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can end your shell commands with `; echo some_marker` and wait until `some_marker` appears in the `stdout`. (And you can also get the exit code with `; echo some_marker $?`)

Comment: That seems like a last resort, day before deadline kind of solution. I disapprove of your answer sir.

Comment: @Magus, your disapproval would be more meaningful if you'd care to provide a better solution. Would you?

Comment: I would if the other question hadn't nailed it already. OP wants a way to find that the process has finished sending output, the other answer gave him exactly that. By the way, I don't shame you, I've used @@@@ as markers for bash/php scripting in darker days. I just wanted to give more relevance to the better answer.

Comment: @Magus, check the comments on the other answer. It doesn't answer the question. Because `adb` **stays open**

Comment: you are correct, the other answer is not good enough

Comment: I've made what I deemed to be a better solution, I'd appreciate your input :)

Comment: After reading your answer for the third time @x00 I finally got it. Genius!

Comment: @Magus, my input is - upvoted. But while the idea of stepping back and considering the problem from another angle slipped my mind, and your solution definitely cleaner, it doesn't really answers the question as it is. Don't know if the reasons stoefln have for `adb` to stay open are good ones, but this answer suits them.

Comment: @stoefln, Glad it helped. But I wouldn't say there is something smart in this. It's definitely a dirty hack

Comment: I understand, that's why I included the reasoning in my answer, adb is just a proxy for adbd, there's no real reason to keep an interactive cli running then. It's no like a repl that keeps state, for example. And now that I rechecked, I don't think your answer is going to work anyways. If you start adb in interactive mode, you can't send it an input and then ; echo some_maker, because all this input is being sent to adb and not to bash. Unless adb has an echo command hahaha

Comment: `Unless adb has an echo command`... well... it has: `adb shell` opens shell `echo 1` prints 1. So what do you mean?

Comment: The reason I am keeping the shell open is that there is a certain overhead in opening it. So for performance reasons. @Magus